# google compute engine: Fresh RHEL 8 image cannot install any packages

Tags: google-compute-engine

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Create a RHEL 8 image using cloud console (any size, any region)
- Connect via ssh and run:

yum install wget

**Actual behaviour:**

The command hangs on 0% for "Google Compute Engine" repo update, then gives up after about a minute or so with the followin error:

```
Google Compute Engine                    [               ===                 ] ---  B/s |   0  B     Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'google-compute-engine':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/google-compute-engine-el8-x86_64-stable/repodata/repomd.xml [Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'google-compute-engine': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

**Expected behaviour:**

Installation should start

As an aside, the Cloud Console has been incredibly slow today - waits up to 5 minutes just to get GCE console page to show. Yet, there is no way to report either of these problems to Google on a paid GC account.

Comment: One problem per post. Your second problem should be asked separately.